# Python 3: "For item in list and item in list:" is this possible?

Tags: python

I have 2 lists and want to make a for loop depending on the number of items in that list, my code:

```
accounts = []
passwords = []

entry1= input('Accounts : ').split()
entry2= input('Passwords : ').split()

accounts.extend(entry1)
passwords.extend(entry2)
```

What I want to do:

```
for account in accounts and password in passwords:
    # do something that matchs accounts[n] with passwords[n] each loop
```

Comment: You want to iterate them in parallel, or as a cartesian product?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to iterate through two lists in parallel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-to-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `zip()` function:

```
accounts = input('Accounts : ').split()
passwords = input('Passwords : ').split()

for account, password in zip(accounts, passwords):
    #do stuff with account and password
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at `zip`:

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip

You would use it as

```
for (account, password) in zip(accounts, passwords):
    do_stuff_with_account_and_password(account, password)
```